# Size of entry of page table

Tags: operating-system, paging

I have a homework question during studying for a test:
You have a new device with logic addresses space of 32 bit and physical addresses space of 34 bit. Size of page is 8KB (2^13 B). Calculate size of page table (of single level).

There are 2^32 / 2^13 = 2^19 entries. And what is the size of entry, I have to assume that it's 4B or I have a way to calculate it?

Comment: People keep asking this same question. It has no answer. There is no standard size of a page table entry. They are usually 4 or 8 bytes but the question should say. Plus, the number of entries can be anything up to the virtual address limit.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already mentioned no. of enteries will be 2^32/2^13, but the page size can be anything (predefined), also you can have operating systems supporting multiple page sizes, hence to best of my understanding you can't calculate the page size through this as it is predefined and virtual memory can be any big.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2^19 entries now each of these entry will be 32 Bit wide so space occupied = (2^19) * (32) Bits